# Using if statement with or to validate arguments for shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm working on a bash script to restart multiple apache instances in different environments.  It's working fine except I'd like to add some logic to ensure only correct arguments are entered.  I've tried the below statement in multiple ways, but I'm not having any luck.  Any suggestions?

```
if [[ $ENVT != qa || $ENVT != qa2 || $ENVT != stageqa || $ENVT != stage ]];
  then
    usage
fi
```

It's when I use the stage environment it's evaluating the first option and invoking the function instead of iterating through as seen with `set -x` turned on.

```
+ ENVT=stage
+ ACTION=stop
+ USER=www
+ '[' 2 -ne 2 ']'
+ [[ stage != qa ]]
+ usage
```

Comment: `||` means "or". Your `if` statement will always be true, since ENVT can't be equal to more than one different string. You probably want `if ! [[ $ENVT = qa || $ENVT = qa2 || $ENVT = stageqa || $ENVT = stage ]]; then usage; fi`

Comment: Thanks, Mark.  I knew there was a way, but I wasn't thinking about how the expression was being evaluated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use multiple `if` condition in this case, use `case` instead:

```
case "$ENVT" in
  (qa|qa2|stageqa|stage) ;;
  (*) usage ;;
esac
```

Comment: I tried using case originally, but I'm not as familiar with it as if statements.  Thanks for giving me the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

*I expected the **qa, qa2** etc to be **dummy** values for more complex tests. If they are just actual **values**, the solution of @Gnouc is **much better** obviously.

I'll leave this answer here for educational value related to the original examples syntax.*

---

You would want an "and" for use with the "!=".

Then, you should not chain many expressions or operators together, but use separate tests like this (it's related to the quotes):

`if [[ a1 != b1 ]] && [[ a2 != b2 ]] && [[ a3 != b3 ]] ...`

Something like:

```
if [[ "$ENVT" != qa ]] && [[ "$ENVT" != qa2 ]] && [[ "$ENVT" != stageqa ]] && [[ "$ENVT" != stage ]];
then
    usage
fi
```

I added quotes around the variables as you see. This is not strictly necessary inside of the double [[ ]], but almost anywhere else, for example in [ ], which are very similar. It's hard enough to get used to always quote, so I'll just keep the quotes.

Comment: You don't need double quote variable in `[[..]]`.

Comment: @Gnouc Thanks, was actually just trying to find that fact in the bash manpage :)